# How can I fetch random words from an electronic dictionary database or text file?

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to get *random* words from the dictionary databases like from the `dict-wn` or freedict's packages? I'm looking for a way to do that by either using a bash script or try a command tool if available.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the wordlist is a plain text file with one word per line, then one option is the `shuf` command e.g.

```
$ shuf -n5 /usr/share/dict/american-english
resuscitated
Lawson
concatenate
nonsmoker's
balmiest
```

See `man shuf`

```
SHUF(1)                          User Commands                         SHUF(1)

NAME
       shuf - generate random permutations

SYNOPSIS
       shuf [OPTION]... [FILE]
       shuf -e [OPTION]... [ARG]...
       shuf -i LO-HI [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION
       Write a random permutation of the input lines to standard output.
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd favour `shuf` for plucking lines from a file. We also need to be careful with the words because it's a tab-delimited file, not just whitespace.

```
$ shuf -n5 /usr/share/dictd/wn.index | cut -d$'\t' -f1
table game
parsi
tetraneuris grandiflora
synonymously
decimal digit
```

`shuf` takes 0.011s here. `sort -R` (even without the `awk`) takes 2.427s. This is because shuf is just seeking through the file *n* times while sort is reading and processing every line... In this case that's 147311 lines.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways to get a random word. Example to retrieve five words:

```
$ sort -R /usr/share/dictd/freedict-nld-eng.index | awk 'NR <= 5 { print $1 }'
verslappen
sport
libretto
golf
kerk
```

See `man sort` for the meaning of the `-R` option (hint: Random). The awk expression filters on the first five records (lines) and prints the first field (not the other columns).

Comment: @rusty No problem, `sort` is not the most efficient program for this purpose either, it creates temporary files for large files. A better program (in terms of memory) would first scan for the number of lines, then pick some random numbers and then scan again for those lines.